# Duplicate config code problem Spring Boot microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

Is there a way to create a spring configuration class and use it to all my microservices?

For example, I have to copy the following configuration class and paste it through all my microservices which means that when I want to make a small change I have to go through all the microservices editing the same class.

I have investigated and the most I could find is to create a module with all the classes in common and import it in my microservices by the pom, what happens with this is that when I want to get the SecurityContextHolder.getContext() this is null for a context issue and I do not know very well how to give solution to this or what other alternatives there are.

```
@Configuration
public class FeignGlobalConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ErrorDecoder errorDecoder() {
        return new RetrieveMessageErrorDecoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor(){
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return requestTemplate -> {
            requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.USERNAME, authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
            requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.CLIENT, authentication.getDetails().toString());
            requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.TOKEN, authentication.getCredentials().toString());
            requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.ROLES, authentication.getAuthorities().toString());
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` is called when the bean is created, so only once. Everything else is called upon execution. Move that line inside the lambda. Make this a config module and/or starter so people can include it.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer so i can mark it as correct and get this resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your bean definition.

The line `Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();` is called when the bean is constructed so only once. After that the reference is used (which is probably `null` at the time of construction.

To solve move tha tline inside the lambda so it gets evaluated each time a request is processed.

```java
@Bean
public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor(){
    return requestTemplate -> {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.USERNAME, authentication.getPrincipal().toString());
        requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.CLIENT, authentication.getDetails().toString());
        requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.TOKEN, authentication.getCredentials().toString());
        requestTemplate.header(JwtClaims.ROLES, authentication.getAuthorities().toString());
    };
}
```